# Overlapping a button on an image

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I want to overlap 10 buttons on an image. I am using RelativeLayout to do the same but as a result, the position of the buttons changes in different devices. So, can someone tell me a workaround for that? This is the xml file for this activity:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/exercise1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="5dp"
tools:context="nmss.example.com.coach.Exercise1">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/humanbody"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_neck"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="145dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="62dp"
    android:text="Neck"
    android:textSize="12sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_shoulder"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="35dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
    android:text="Shoulder"
    android:textSize="12sp"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_biceps"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="135dp"
    android:text="Biceps"
    android:textSize="12sp"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_forearm"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="3dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="195dp"
    android:text="Forearm"
    android:textSize="12sp"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_quads"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="68dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="315dp"
    android:text="Quads"
    android:textSize="12sp"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_chest"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="145dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    android:text="Chest"
    android:textSize="12sp"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_abs"
    android:layout_width="65dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="150dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="160dp"
    android:text="Abs"
    android:textSize="12sp"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_triceps"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="246dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="125dp"
    android:text="Triceps"
    android:textSize="12sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_mid_back"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="215dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="175dp"
    android:text="Middle back"
    android:textSize="12sp"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_calves"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="210dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="400dp"
    android:text="Calves"
    android:textSize="12sp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[This is the view in Android Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PqyIR.png)

Comment: Never hard code the sizes like this, 25dp, 
Add this link to your dependencies, to get the dimensions for every screen.

Comment: you can user contraint layout :->  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `LinearLayout` instead of `RelativeLayout`.
Try to arrange your image buttons on top,bottom,right and left using the percentages.
You also need to create different Layouts Folders in your *res folder* for all devices and use the dimensions accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Never hard code the sizes like this, 25dp, 
Add this link to your dependencies, to get the dimensions for every screen.

```
 compile 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.4'
```

Its uses is like this,

```
  android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_110sdp"
```

After writing, @dimen/...Ctrl+Space, you can see the value of dimensions from 1dp to 600dp. Try it, its very useful.